# Why is my return function not working for each object i created , using list?

Tags: c++, list, object, oop

I created a class that contains a set function and a get function , for a string variable.
This is the header file.

```
 class Stock
{
private:
    std::string stockName;
public:
    Stock();
 void setStockName(std::string _stockName);
 std::string getStockName();
```

This is the cpp file of the class:

```
Stock::Stock()
{
    
}

void Stock::setStockName(std::string _stockName)
{
    this->stockName = _stockName;
}

std::string Stock::getStockName()
{
    return this->stockName;
}
```

In the main function i created a `std::list` , a `std::vector` could be better but I decided to go along with a `std::list`. I first make the compiler ask the `amount of stocks` that are needed , with a `for loop` i create stocks `based on the amount entered`. With a `for each loop` i set their names. For debugging purposes i created another  `for each loop` to see if the names will pop up but it seems they don't.

This is the main function:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <list>
#include "Stock.h"


int main()
{
    
    int amountOfStocks;
    std::list <Stock> Stocks;
    std::cout << "Enter amount of stocks!\n";
    std::cin >> amountOfStocks;
   
    for (int i = 1; i <= amountOfStocks; i++)
    {
       //Make stocks based on the amount entered
        Stock _stock  ;
        Stocks.push_back(_stock);
    }
    std::cout << "Enter name for each stock!\n";
    
    //Set the name of each stock
    for(Stock obj : Stocks)
    {
        std::string stockName;
        std::cin >> stockName;
        obj.setStockName(stockName);
    }
    
    //Get the name of each Stock
    for (Stock obj : Stocks)
    {
        std::cout <<obj.getStockName() << " , ";
    }
}
```

Comment: In your for-loop, you index the elements by means of copies of the objects instead of object references. Try rewriting it to `for(Stock &obj : Stocks)` (notice the ampersand).

Comment: In `for(Stock obj : Stocks)` you are making a copy of each `Stock` object and setting the name on that copy. Use a reference instead: `for(Stock &obj : Stocks)`

Comment: On a side note: you also create copies when you print the names. You can use `for (Stock const & obj : Stocks)`. Using `const&` will ensure you are not modifying the elements (and also not copying it).

Comment: Tnx for the responces. Huge help!

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
for(Stock obj : Stocks)
{
    std::string stockName;
    std::cin >> stockName;
    obj.setStockName(stockName);
}
```

to this

```
for(Stock& obj : Stocks)
{
    std::string stockName;
    std::cin >> stockName;
    obj.setStockName(stockName);
}
```

The extra `&` is crucial. In your version `obj` is a separate variable that is not part of your list. You are changing `obj` but because `obj` is not in the list, the list does not change.

With my version `obj` is a **reference** to the value in the list. So when `obj` is changed what actually changes is the value in the list.

Comment: Could've closed this as a dupe. This is a very common question. Moreover, it was a typo.

Comment: Tnx for the responce!